# Unable to process multiple polygons using SpatialPolygons object

Tags: r, polygon, sf, sp, rgeos

I have a list with 4 objects, each object is a data frame. The data frame is the coordinate matrix of each polygon. I would like calculate the total area of the 4 polygons and then draw the voronoi tessellation.
Here is my workflow,
first, I convert the data frame within the list to polygon:

```
  Region_HE_srl <- lapply(Region_HE,FUN= function(x) Polygon(x))
```

Then, I create the SpatialPolygons object:

```
  Region_HE_sp <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(Region_HE_srl,length(Region_HE))))
```

Now that the SpatialPolygons object is created:
[image]
I used the 'gArea' function from the 'rgeos' package to calculate the area.

```
  area <- gArea(Region_HE_sp, byid = TRUE)
```

Normally, when there is only 1 polygon within the SpatialPolygon object, this function works fine, but now as there are 4 polygons, an error occurs:

> Error in createPolygonsComment(p) :
> rgeos_PolyCreateComment: orphaned hole, cannot find containing polygon for hole at index 1

Same thing when I applied the voronoi.polygons function from 'SDraw' package.

```
  voronoi.tess <- SDraw::voronoi.polygons(pts_ppp, Region_HE_sp)
```

The error occurs again. As the package claimed that the bounding polygon parameter should be a spatialpolygons object, I cannot figure out why this error happened.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R thinks one or more of your polygons are holes, and a hole has to be inside a non-hole.

Hole detection is done in the `Polygon` function:

```
     Polygon(coords, hole=as.logical(NA))

  coords: 2-column numeric matrix with coordinates; first point (row)
          should equal last coordinates (row); if the hole argument is
          not given, the status of the polygon as a hole or an island
          will be taken from the ring direction, with clockwise meaning
          island, and counter-clockwise meaning hole
```

So you either have to reverse the holey Polygon, or set `hole=FALSE` in your `Polygon` function call:

```
    hole: logical value for setting polygon as hole or not; if the hole
          argument is not given, the status of the polygon as a hole or
          an island will be taken from the ring direction, with
          clockwise meaning island, and counter-clockwise meaning hole
```

Comment: Solved my problem, thank you!